# Distribute XNA as a standalone zip or exe (no installer needed)?

Tags: xna, distribution

I want to know how would I distribute my XNA such that it won't distribute as an installer/setup files? I just want a zip of files such that when the user can run instantly after extracting into a folder. I am making a small prototype of some functionalities, and I would like my co-workers to visually see it so that we can communicate better. However, this must means I must frequently release my projects (as I update it frequently), so I want to know a way to produce easy-to-launch distribution.

I tried to turn Build option in Visual Studio to Release, and try copy and zip all the files inside Release folder. However, when I zip it and send to my coworkers, they said nothing comes up after they open the exe.

Comment: Look at ClickOnce it creates easy installer that can be updated via web, so its basically one click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your co-workers need to have the [.Net Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21) and the [XNA Framework 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20914) installed. I don't think there's an easy way around that. Get them to install these first, then you can distribute the exes in a zip file with no problems.

Comment: They said they have both 3.5 and 4.0, so I think the problem is there may be more dependent files that I didn't include in the zip. All I put into my zip is the exe and Content folder (which is where all my resources are). However, some of the resources are custom files (import into XNA but only set it to Copy Always with no compiling)

Comment: They have both the .Net Framework AND the XNA Framework?  (3.5 and 4.0 respectively)

Comment: XNA Framework too? I think they miss that one, so where can they download that?

Comment: @user1542 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20914

Comment: The link was also in my original answer, if you read carefully.

Comment: Yup, I've sent an XNA "game" as a zip before, it wouldn't load until both .net and xna were installed but then it worked fine.